# Mobile Service + DocumentDB attachment

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-cosmosdb

Here is my stack:

- iOS and Android apps
- DocumentDB
- Mobile Services backed by Javascript
- Azure Sites backed by Javascript

What I'm looking to do is abstract the knowledge of DocumentDB from our apps as we are building white label solutions and we may need to on-the-fly scale out DocumentDB instances.  With an abstraction type of service we can essentially shard our docdb instances based on certain data sent from the application.

Right now this would consist of 2 operations that I would like to create mobile services for.  One to get JSON data and another to fetch attachments that are associated with documents.  This is where my trouble is.  I have a pass-through service written in just NodeJS that is deployable.  I like the security model associated with Mobile Services so I want to adapt my code into that.  The issue lies in piping the DocDB response to the Mobile Services Response.  First it was the Mobile Services default headers attempting to be set and failing, so I temporarily override that function.  Now Mobile Services just never responds, until a timeout occurs.  Here is a code snippet:

```js
exports.get = function (req, res) {
...
// .then().fail() always pushed into the fail() block, but if I use the 2 function in .then() way it works.
client.readMediaAsync(mediaUrl).then(
    // Success
    function (media) {
        // Set up caching and proxy the response
        media.headers["cache-control"] = "max-age=2147483647, max-stale=2147483647";
        media.headers["pragma"] = "cache";
        for (var responseHeader in media.headers) {
            if (media.headers.hasOwnProperty(responseHeader) && "content-location" != responseHeader) {
                res.setHeader(responseHeader, media.headers[responseHeader]);
            }
        }
        // Block further header modification
        res.setHeader = function(field, val){};
        media.result.pipe(res, {end: true});
        //media.result.on("end", function () {
        //    console.log("attachment#end");
        //    res.status(200).send(); // have also tried .end() with no luck
        //});
    },

    // Error
    function (mediaError) {
        console.error("documentClient.readMediaAsync fail->" + JSON.stringify(mediaError));
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(mediaError));
    }
); ...
```

The line that reads media.result.pipe(...) is where it gets hung up.  Again, this code works outside of Mobile Services.  I've been using the change -> commit -> test -> repeat cycle but haven't had any luck.  Does anybody know how to properly pipe a stream into the response within a Mobile Service?

Comment: What's your error message? Each time when we hit the script in Mobile Service and get an error, it will be logged into files. In Mobile Service portal, click **LOGS** tab, we can check the error message.

Comment: No errors get logged.  After a while it appears to timeout and returns this html; https://goo.gl/92oQh6 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the non-promises version of the node documentdb sdk.  There must be something that gets mixed up in the response with the promises (although it looked pretty straightforward).

Here is the functioning code snippet:

       `clientSync.readMedia(mediaUrl, function (err, mediaStream) {
            if (!err && mediaStream) {
                mediaStream.headers["cache-control"] = "max-age=2147483647, max-stale=2147483647";
                mediaStream.headers["pragma"] = "cache";
                for (var responseHeader in mediaStream.headers) {
                    if (mediaStream.headers.hasOwnProperty(responseHeader) && "content-location" != responseHeader) {
                        res.setHeader(responseHeader, mediaStream.headers[responseHeader]);
                    }
                }
                res.setHeader = function (field, val) {
                };
                mediaStream.pipe(res);
                mediaStream.on('end', function () {
                    res.status(200).end();
                });
            } else {
                console.error("attachment(" + mediaUrl + ") catch->" + JSON.stringify(err.detail) + "; " + err.message + "; " + err.stack);
                res.status(400).send();
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to reproduce your issue, I got the HTML code after requesting for a while, however I also got the error message in LOGS tab, it looked like:

> `An unhandled exception occurred. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:679:11) at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:59:22) at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:518:10) at addDefaultHeaders (D:\home\site\wwwroot\runtime\request\requesthandler.js:582:9) at ServerResponse.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\runtime\request\requesthandler.js:291:13) at ServerResponse._.wrap [as end] (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:692:22) at onend (stream.js:66:10) at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20) at afterRead (fs.js:1335:12) at Object.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:367:17)`

According this log, I set header before pipe into the response, and which worked fine in my test.

Here is my simple code snippet:

`exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var fs = require("fs");
    response.setHeader = function(field, val){};
    fs.createReadStream('files/123.txt').pipe(response,{end: true});
};`

Comment: I was also getting the error your cited, which is why I added the line `res.setHeader = function(field, val){};` as you also did.  I will backtrack a little and try to take DocumentDB out of the mix and just pipe an image to see if that works, which may indicate a stream issue (at least an issue with Mobile Services, as I use the SDK to pipe in a standalone NodeJS app) with the DocumentDB SDK.

Comment: Even set `response.setHeader = function(field, val){};`, you still get this issue? could you tell me, `readMediaAsync()` is your custom function or which sdk contains this API? Cause I didn't find this API reference in DocumentDB Node.js SDK.

Comment: `readMediaAsync()` comes from the DocumentDB Promises SDK.  https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node-q/blob/master/documentclientwrapper.js#L1131

Comment: generally, `pipe()` is pulling out all data form a readable stream and writing into a writable stream, simply `readable.pipe(writable)`. For detail:https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options. And the `readMediaAsync()` returns a object, and `media.result` in your code should be the binary content of media attachment. you can `console.log(media.result)` it and check in log to see the type the the variable.

Comment: Your simple example of just serving a static file works.  There must be something else going on with the media.result.pipe() that is getting hung up.  We use the same code outside of a Mobile Service and it works fine. I will keep looking.